# How to burn a region free DVD from a DVD movie locked to a specific region?

Tags: dvd, burning, unlock

A friend of mine have a DVD movie locked to a different region. Hopefully, I seem to have a region free DVD player in my laptop.

How can I burn a region free copy of his DVD movie so my friend can watch it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could give "K9Copy - KDE tool to backup DVDs" a try.

[image: Install via the software center]

It's very much capable of disassembling the individual streams, putting them back together (even customising the selection of audio/video tracks) and then burning it to a new disc.

It seems it's not even capable of putting a region code onto a blank DVD, so (ab)use that as a feature!

A sort of dedicated tutorial on how to do this is [on this random blog](http://itforthecommonman.blogspot.nl/2010/02/ubuntu-dvd-remove-region-on-copy.html). Comes down to:

1. Select DVD source.
2. Select "Rip and encode" as destination.
3. Select the elements you want to "rip". It's useful to leave out some unwanted streams/titles/chapters.
4. Select some encoding options, but just use "copy" to leave the contents of the streams untouched.
5. Once finished it will ask you to load a blank DVD to burn.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [Brasero](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brasero) [image: Install Brasero] for this. It's fairly trivial.

Just make an image of the DVD, then burn the image to a blank one.

Comment: Yeah, Brasero will work fine too, probably. If I recall correctly, that has less options regarding DVD-videos, though. I've upgraded your answer, and it's a nice suggestion, so +1.