# Burning a DVD without a region code

Tags: dvd, burning

I have European DVDs and would like to watch them on my American DVD player, which complains about regional codes. So I would like to burn them without region codes.

I know this has been asked and answered before, BUT... the favorite tool seems to be K9Copy which, as far as I can tell, is no longer available for download. So now what? Brasero absolutely kept the regional code.

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to burn a region free DVD from a DVD movie locked to a specific region?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239158/how-to-burn-a-region-free-dvd-from-a-dvd-movie-locked-to-a-specific-region)

Comment: Downvote as you have given no effort in searching for similar answers in askubuntu

Comment: @rancho Mind you k9copy is not available from the Xenial repositories making the question you linked to not completely useful...

Comment: Then edit the question and ask how to install k9copy

Comment: Before you edit it, there was a link in an old answer to download k9copy for Ubuntu 14.04, but that old link is now broken.

Comment: No way that brasero or anything else writes region coding on to dvd media. Your bigger issue may be  you're going from PAL to NTSC or burning as PAL which many US dvd players can't handle

Answer (score 2):

From xenial on the k9copy package in ppa:tomtomtom/k9copy provides the Qt5 version. To install k9copy in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/k9copy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install k9copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, I get that you would like to try alternatives to k9Copy.

I've found two such apps although I haven't tried myself, so I can't talk from my own experience. But maybe you, or other users, will find them to be useful.

- [DVD5](http://dvd95.sourceforge.net/) which can be downloaded from [sourceforge website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvd95/files/).
- [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) beta which can be downloaded from their [forum](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224).

Comment: SourceForge has resumed its evil practice of packaging its own bits inside of downloadable open source binary files, even though it publicly announced that it has stopped doing this now that SourceForge is under new management. I confirmed that this is still occurring as recently as last week. So I recommend you find an alternative link for DVD5.

Comment: I have nothing against k9copy,  but I didn't know where to get it. Karel helped me with that. I'm new to mucking about in Linux, but I gather the first command told the computer which repository to search in.

Comment: I get errors. 
1(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING) - English(i!*N_ARGUMENT_M...
I'm also new to  mucking with media, I have no idea what that means.

MakeMKV looked promising, but I got stalled out in the installation. I've gotten to "make -f makefile.common" and was told No targets. Stop.

VLC and K3B seemed great for everything else, but not this.